# Can not update bar chart values in Chart.js 2.0.0 alpha3

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am trying to draw a live bar chart using latest Chart.js alpha. I want to dynamically update both values and labels. However, when I try to address a specific bar, say, number 3:

```
$.each(my_chart.datasets, function(i, dataset){
    dataset.data[3].fillColor = fc;
    dataset.data[3].value = v;
});
```

I get a jQuery error, stating that I cannot get length of one of the parameters.

When I try to access the chart's dataset like this:

```
my_chart.datasets[0].data = new_values_array;
```

I get the `TypeError: undefined is not an object`

What is the right way to address this problem in the newest alpha? The examples suggest updating the whole array, but I can't see the difference between updating the whole array or addressing a specific element. Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update point by point, like so

```
$.each(my_chart.data.datasets, function (i, dataset) {
    dataset.metaData[3].custom = {
        backgroundColor: "green"
    };
    dataset.data[3] = 2.5;
});

my_chart.update();
```

Replace `green` by `fc` and `2.5` by `v`

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6qt14tpj/

Comment: Hello and thank you! Are you from the chart.js team? If so, then amazing job!

What about changing labels? 
Is there some kind documentation for this release?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not from the Chart.js team. You might want to drop them a note at GitHub though - I'm sure they'll love the feedback! Labels ==> my_chart.data.labels[3] = "myNewLabel". They have an open issue (2.0 milestone) for updating the docs - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/1248. Till then, you can probably check the 2.0 dev branch - esp. the samples folder https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/tree/v2.0-dev/samples

Comment: It keeps changing a bit here and there though - so if it doesn't work on first try, you might want to just fiddle around a bit to get it right.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen those samples, it seems the alpha is pretty stable. Not enough info to use it, though. Thanks again!